# httpd running but Apache not listening

Tags: linux, freebsd, apache-http-server

How to debug a situation where httpd is running but netstat shows Apache is not listening?

This is a server where I run two apaches (v2.2), one for my prod systems and one for dev, with separate IP addresses for prod and dev. Both listen on port 80.

Today when I tried to start my dev httpd, it started fine but I was unable to connect. *nslookup* indicates that DNS is okay. *ps aux* shows both apaches running, but *netstat* shows only prod is listening. I have confirmed that httpd.conf for dev server is loading and it contains correct Listen commands.

How can I debug this from here? How can Apache start but not listen?

Comment: are you listening on the same interface that netstat is reporting?

Comment: Won't netstat -la report all interfaces on server? Not sure how I would point netstat at dev.

Answer (score -1):

This turned out to be a firewall issue. The IP address for dev was not opened in the firewall.